# Symfony/PostGreSQL : An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

i'm using Symfony 4.3.4 with a PostGreSQL server version 12.1, and i have some difficulties to connect my project to the database.

I edited the .env file like that :

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password@127.0.0.1:5432/database?serverVersion=12.1&charset=utf8
```

After that i tried to make migrations, but i had an error because of php extensions.
So i added this to the php.ini file : (i'm using WAMP with PHP 7.2.18)

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
```

After that, i was able to make migrations.
My problem is, when i try to register a new account in my app, it returns me the error :

```
An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver | in AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php.
```

And i have this problem with all routes that interact with my tables
I don't understand why i am able to make migrations, but i can't do anything else.

Thanks you for the help.

Comment: Try with `pgsql://` instead of `postgresql://`

Comment: Can you share the **exact** error message? Additionally, have you checked through `phpinfo()` whether these extensions **really** got enabled? It should not be relevant whether you use `pgsql://` or `postgresql://`, as they are aliases for the same driver